# Full-screen background image on container-fluid

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to get a background image to fill the screen on a container-fluid div and it is not working. I've done quite a bit of research, but here's the problem: the website I'm working on is on a platform on which I have absolutely no ability to edit the html. This is the website for my HOA (Homeowner's Association), and they use a god-awful platform - HOA Express. The only customization ability I have is a "Custom CSS" box on the website settings page. The [website's url](http://www.AtascocitaForest.org) is.

I had a full-screen background image on the site previously, but this week they updated their whole system from something circa 2002 to I assume a version of bootstrap (with which I am not very well-versed), and in doing so they wiped out all existing custom css, so I have to go in and redo everything.

Any ideas on what I might try? Is this even possible?

Comment: What prevents you from doing: .container-fluid { background: url(http://url-to-image.org/image.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover; } or something similar

Comment: I have applied the code you suggested to the site, but it does not fill the whole screen. Please feel free to take a look to see what I mean.

Comment: It looks like a contributing problem may be that my image is being scaled somehow. The image is natively 1920x1080, and because I don't have FTP access to upload any files, I am hosting the background image on google images. When I view the photo properties in the browser it's showing as 1,494px × 840px. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: You could recover the old CSS from here: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.atascocitaforest.org/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `background-size: cover` from my example. However this will "zoom" the image, and I don't think that is what you want. I suppose you want the image to fill the viewport, and stay there. To achieve this you need to set your background to cover "100%" and be fixed.

So basically you add this.

```
.container-fluid {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This is what I currently have: `.container-fluid { 
background: url(https://goo.gl/KQMhPd) no-repeat center center fixed; -
webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: 100% 100%;}
background-attachment: fixed;
}` Correct, or incorrect? It's still not working. My image is being downscaled for some reason.

Comment: It is not what you currently have. I am looking at your website right now, and the only thing you have is `background: url(https://goo.gl/KQMhPd) no-repeat fixed center`

Comment: Delete whatever you have and add the following: .container-fluid {
    background: url(https://goo.gl/KQMhPd) no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

If you are going to do things differently yourself then there is no point in asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Let me clarify - the code I posted is what I have in the "custom CSS" box on the site's backend. I firebugged the code and you are right - it's not showing up, so I think there may be something wrong on the website host's end. So we're both right. I'll follow up with their support department and see what I can find out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to follow up, I did communicate with their customer support and their system does block CSS that it thinks might be erroneous or that affects core aspects of the website. They will not give me any further information on criteria for CSS. Apparently, trying to remove css drop shadows is "threatening" to the website. So frustrating...

Comment: And this doesn't work? .container-fluid { background: url(https://goo.gl/KQMhPd) no-repeat fixed center; background-size: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;   
width:100%;
```

Add background-size and width to the image

Answer (score -1):

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.